# Bootstrap layout issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Working with a Bootstrap template (free-responsive-template-photography). Changed photos, colors to something I have and like. Started to add popovers to the photos for description, but now the layout has gone from 3-4 thumbnails wide (span3 or span4) to all the photos being stacked vertical. 1 column now instead of 3 or 4. Haven't changed any of the CSS other than colors. Where have I gone awry? Any ideas where to get this layout corrected?

```
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
        <article class="span4">
<h2>Popover with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>
<div class="clear"></div>
<ul><img src="img/bar/tBDR-BM4.png" id="BDR-BM4" class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-original-title="">BDR-BM4</a>
</ul>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="js/pbootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script>
$(function ()
{ $("#BDR-BM4").popover({title: 'BDR-BM4', content: "Receivers are custom built using precision CNC machines, 7075 T6 aluminum,USA forgings. Must Ship to FFL Holder"});
});
</script>
<ul><img src="img/bar/tBDR-B12.png" id="BDR-B12" class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-original-title="">BDR-B12</a>
</ul>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="js/pbootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script>
$(function ()
{ $("#BDR-B12").popover({title: 'BDR-15A', content: "Receivers are custom built using precision CNC machines, 7075 T6 aluminum,USA forgings. Must Ship to FFL Holder"});
});
</script>
<ul><img src="img/bar/tBDR-B20H.png" id="BDR-B20H" class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-original-title="">BDR-B20H</a>
</ul>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="js/pbootstrap-popover.js"></script>

<script>
$(function ()
{ $("#BDR-B20H").popover({title: 'BDR-B20H', content: "Receivers are custom built using precision CNC machines, 7075 T6 aluminum,USA forgings. Must Ship to FFL Holder"});
});
</script>
<ul><img src="img/bar/tBDR-B16F.png" id="BDR-B16F" class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-original-title="">BDR-B16F</a>
</ul>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="js/pbootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script>
$(function ()
{ $("#BDR-B16F").popover({title: 'BDR-B16F', content: "Receivers are custom built using precision CNC machines, 7075 T6 aluminum,USA forgings. Must Ship to FFL Holder"});
});
</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: can you post the test page or show us wat exactly is happening ??

Comment: http://webpages.charter.net/tfbone/Popover.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the following code multiple times on the page , place it in the footer only once .

```
 <script src="js/jquery.min.js">
 <script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js">
 <script src="js/pbootstrap-popover.js">
```

Also remove the `clear div` after the `article tag` i.e

```
<div class="clear"></div>/*remove*/
```

I have cleaned up your code a bit and rearranged a few things , use the following in your body and see if its the desired result you wish to attain:
[Jsfiddle with the result Please check](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/eYpS6/show)

[image: screenshot of result in browser]

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <article class="span12">
         <h2>Popover with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>

       <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
            <ul>
                <img src="http://webpages.charter.net/tfbone/img/bar/tBDR-BM4.png" id="BDR-BM4"
                class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-original-title="">BDR-BM4</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <ul>
                <img src="http://webpages.charter.net/tfbone/img/bar/tBDR-B12.png" id="BDR-B12"
                class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-original-title="">BDR-B12</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <ul>
                <img src="http://webpages.charter.net/tfbone/img/bar/tBDR-B20H.png" id="BDR-B20H"
                class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-original-title="">BDR-B20H</a>
            </ul>
</div>
<div class="span3">
    <ul>
        <img src="http://webpages.charter.net/tfbone/img/bar/tBDR-B16F.png" id="BDR-B16F"
        class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-original-title="">BDR-B16F</a>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>

</script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="js/pbootstrap-popover.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#BDR-BM4").popover({
            title: 'BDR-BM4',
            content: "Black Dawn Lower Receivers are custom built using precision CNC machines, 7075 T6 aluminum,USA forgings. Must Ship to FFL Holder"
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $("#BDR-B12").popover({
            title: 'BDR-15A',
            content: "Black Dawn Lower Receivers are custom built using precision CNC machines, 7075 T6 aluminum,USA forgings. Must Ship to FFL Holder"
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $("#BDR-B20H").popover({
            title: 'BDR-B20H',
            content: "Black Dawn Lower Receivers are custom built using precision CNC machines, 7075 T6 aluminum,USA forgings. Must Ship to FFL Holder"
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $("#BDR-B16F").popover({
            title: 'BDR-B16F',
            content: "Black Dawn Lower Receivers are custom built using precision CNC machines, 7075 T6 aluminum,USA forgings. Must Ship to FFL Holder"
        });
    });
</script>
      </div>
   </article>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks! Been looking at too long with no change. Knew someone would see it. Thanks again!!